# how to find the word and split the integer and characters in a string

Tags: c#, string, split

Please tell me this question answer please ...

```
string ss="pradeep rao having 2years exp";
```

in the above string i want to find the word of years(or) year and if match the the word,i wnt split the word like

```
string s="2";
string s1="years(or)year"
```

thanks 
pradeep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way would be with a regular expression like so:

```
Regex = new Regex("(\d+)(years?)");

Match match = regex.Match(ss);
if(match.Success)
{
  string s = match.Groups[1];
  string s1 = match.Groups[2];
}
```

Comment: Unrecognized escape sequence         System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(\d+)(years?)");

Comment: HAI DAVE SEXTON THIS ONE WORKING ONLY TO THE INTEGERS I WANT INTEGERS AS WELL AS DECIMALS WELL WORK BOTH CAN U PLEASE SEND ME SOLUTION................PLEASE

Comment: if you are using c# then use a verbatim string for the regex like so: @"(\d+)(years?)" otherwise the backslash will cause confusion. If you want decimals as well then try @"(\d+\.?\d*)(years?)"

Answer (score 1):

No solution but a hint in the right direction:

1. Search for the text string 'years' in your ss string. You will get an index. (e.g. 21)
2. Use the begining of the string ss, till the index to look for the number. (start at 21 and work your way back)

Answer (score 0):

```
string ss = "pradeep rao having 2years exp";

            string[] SPLIT = ss.split(' ');

            for (int i = 0; i < SPLIT.Length; i++)
            {
                if (SPLIT[i].Contains("years") || SPLIT[i].Contains("year"))
                {
                    //SPLIT[i] is the required word split it or use Substring property to get the desired result
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: how to split word,if suppose i am using 10years in the string